# Discord login and join server selenium

Tags: python, selenium, discord

I would like to create this bot, which having in input a token and an invitation code to a discord server, makes access via selenium to the discord account, and enters a server with the invitation code given in input. I am able to log into the account with the token given in input but I am unable to log into a server. Please help me :)

```
from os import system
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import requests, time

token = str(input("Here your token: "))
invite = input("Server invite(only code): ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://discord.com/login')
sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('window.t = "' + token + '";window.localStorage = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage;window.setInterval(() => window.localStorage.token = `"${window.t}"`); window.location.reload();')
system('cls')

def join():
    headers = {
        "Authorization": token, 
        "User-Agent": "HERE MY USER AGENT"
    }

    r = requests.post(f"ttps://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{invite}", headers = headers)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("Server joined :)")
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        print(f"[{r.status_code}] {r.text}")
        time.sleep(20)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    join()
```

Comment: Can you please add any errors you are getting when trying to log in?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs no errors

Comment: are any credentials required to log into the server ?